# How can a scrollable area retrieve the size of what is being displayed?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

In my application I've got the following situation:

I've got a Windows Form with a Tab Control with several tabs. Each tab contains arbitrary content which is added by other classes upon startup or during runtime.

I want to set up the tabs in a way that scrollbars appear automatically as soon as the Form is too small for the tab's panel to display everything.

What I've tried so far is setting the tab page's `AutoScroll = true` and setting the  `AutoScrollMinSize` property to the size of the panel.

This did not work as expected as the panel's `Size` always seems to be (200, 100) independent of its contents.

I've created a small example application (code below) which demonstrates the issue. If you resize the form, you'll see that scroll bars only appear if the Form gets smaller than the panel (default size of (200, 100)) rather than the text box in the panel (size of 300, 150). If you set `AutoScrollMinSize` manually (uncomment line 34), it behaves as expected.

The question is: How can the tab page retrieve the actual size of what is displayed in it?

I could probably recurse through all controls and try calculating the size myself - but this feels really bad.

PS: Please do not suggest setting the size of the panel to the size of the label, as the actual panels are much more complex than that. ;-)

---

Code:

Simply create an Application in Visual Studio and override Program.cs with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollbarTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var sampleForm = CreateSampleForm();

            Application.Run(sampleForm);
        }

        private static Form CreateSampleForm()
        {
            var sampleForm = new Form() { };
            var tabControl = new TabControl() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            var tabPage = new TabPage("Test") { AutoScroll = true };
            sampleForm.Controls.Add(tabControl);
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

            var samplePanel = CreateSamplePanel();
            tabPage.Controls.Add(samplePanel);

            // this does not provide the right size
            tabPage.AutoScrollMinSize = samplePanel.Size;

            // uncomment this to make it work
            //tabPage.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 150);

            return sampleForm;
        }

        private static Control CreateSamplePanel()
        {
            // As an example, create a panel with a text box with a fixed size.
            var samplePanel = new Panel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            var sampleSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 150);
            var textBox = new TextBox() 
            { 
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                MinimumSize = sampleSize,
                MaximumSize = sampleSize,
                Size = sampleSize
            };
            samplePanel.Controls.Add(textBox);

            return samplePanel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tab page doesn't know about the panel contains. Why don't you set the scroll bars on the panel instead.

Comment: In that case I would have the same problem on the panel. The panels usually consist of a TableLayoutPanel with several subpanels with several controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `samplePanel.Size` returns (200,100). In your `CreateSamplePanel` method, if you set `samplePanel.MinimumSize = sampleSize;` then your code will work.

Panels don't calculate their size properties (e.g. `Size`, `MinimumSize`, `PreferredSize`) based on their child controls. You will have to subclass Panel and provide that behavior. Even `TableLayoutPanel` and `FlowLayoutPanel` don't correctly calculate the `PreferredSize` property, which is surprising. At the very least, normally you override the `GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)` method, and optionally have the `MinimumSize` property return the `PreferredSize` property.

It's worth noting that `DockStyle.Fill` and `MinimumSize` are at odds with each other. `TabPage` controls are inherently `DockStyle.Fill` mode, which is why you have to set the `AutoScrollMinSize` property.

**Edit:** Isn't there any existing function which retrieves the total required size of a list of controls (recursively), e.g. through their X/Y and Size?

It's up to the host container itself (e.g. `TableLayoutPanel`) to calculate its `PreferredSize` correctly because only it knows the exact details of how its layout is performed.

You can set the `AutoSize` property to true and then hope that `GetPreferredSize(...)/PreferredSize` calculates the right size. For `TableLayoutPanel`, I recall there was a case where it wasn't calculating correctly and I had to subclass it and override the `GetPreferredSize(...)` method. `GetPreferredSize(...)` won't be called unless `AutoSize` is true.

If you're talking about a plain `Panel` or `UserControl`, by default these use the WYSIWYG `LayoutEngine`, and do not calculate the `PreferredSize`. You could subclass and then calculate maximum `control.X + control.Width` and same thing for height, and use that as the preferred size.

First try setting `AutoSize` to true and see if that works for you. If not, you might have to override the `GetPreferredSize(...)` method. Here is a crude example:

```
   [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var sampleForm = new Form() { AutoScroll = true };

        var panel = new MyPanel() { AutoSize = true, AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink, BackColor = Color.LightYellow };

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Button b = new Button { Text = "Button" + panel.Controls.Count, AutoSize = true };
                b.Click += delegate {
                    MessageBox.Show("Preferred Size: " + panel.PreferredSize);
                };
                panel.Controls.Add(b, j, i);
            }
        }

        sampleForm.Controls.Add(panel);
        Application.Run(sampleForm);
    }

    private class MyPanel : TableLayoutPanel {
        public override Size MinimumSize {
            get {
                return PreferredSize;
            }
            set {

            }
        }

        public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize) {
            Size s = new Size();
            int[] harr = new int[100];//this.RowCount];
            int[] warr = new int[100];//this.ColumnCount];
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
                var cell = this.GetPositionFromControl(c);
                var ps = c.PreferredSize;
                Padding m = c.Margin;
                int w = ps.Width + m.Horizontal;
                int h = ps.Height + m.Vertical;
                if (w > warr[cell.Column])
                    warr[cell.Column] = w;
                if (h > harr[cell.Row])
                    harr[cell.Row] = h;
            }

            foreach (int w in warr)
                s.Width += w;
            foreach (int h in harr)
                s.Height += h;

            return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The thing is in my actual application, I don't have a `sampleSize`. Isn't there any existing function which retrieves the total required size of a list of controls (recursively), e.g. through their X/Y and Size?